# android studio in 14 android version and 34 targate sdk version

Tags: android, sdk

getting this error in android studio in 14 android version and 34 targate sdk version

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.devsupport.BridgeDevSupportManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~DqaLE4qYSl0-C9JLusIusw==/com.logicwind.contractgenie-wN7u1LL2Qvg2oFjrMZuxyQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~DqaLE4qYSl0-C9JLusIusw==/com.logicwind.contractgenie-wN7u1LL2Qvg2oFjrMZuxyQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~DqaLE4qYSl0-C9JLusIusw==/com.logicwind.contractgenie-wN7u1LL2Qvg2oFjrMZuxyQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

want to run the app on 34 sdk my React native version is 0.71.8

Comment: please share the build.gradle file you're using. thanks.

Comment: hey can you please let me know the specific react native version which only supports android 14 and compile sdk 34 as i'm having react native version 0.64.1 but it's not working for sdk 34